# MS EXCEL: Find End Date based on Start Date and Total Hours:Minutes

Tags: date, time, excel-formula

Using a MS Excel Formula (2010) - I would like to calculate and find the `End Date` (`mm/dd/yyyy`) and `End Time` (`hours:minutes`), based on a given `Start Date`,  `Beginning Time` and `Total Hours`.

Located in Cells: `A2`, `B2`, `C2` are the actual inputted date, time and hours

```
Begin Date: 01/27/2017
Begin Time: 9:30 AM 
Total Hours.: 44hrs 30mins
```

---

[image]

I would like to know if there's a formula that can calculate the provided inputted information above that will output the following results in adjacent cells (i.e., `D2` and `E2`).

```
End Date: 01/29/2017
End Time: 6:00 AM
```

Comment: Is "Total Hours.": in `C1` while "44hrs 30mins" is in `C2`, or is that entire string in `C2`?

Comment: Hours are manually inputted and minutes are rounded up in 4 quarter increments (.00, .25, .50, & .75) see attached snap shot for assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to work with these dates and formatting styles:

[image]

**Formulas:**

- Cell B5  >> `=SUM(B1;B2)`
- Cell B7  >> `=SUM(B5;B3)`
- Cell B9  >> `=TEXT(B7;"dd/mm/yyyy")`
- Cell B10 >> `=TEXT(B7;"hh:mm")` or you can use `=TEXT(B7;"hh:mm AM/PM")`

---

Or using the layout you provided:

[image]

**Formulas:**

- Cell D2  >> `=SUM(A2;B2)`
- Cell E2  >> `=SUM(D2;C2)`
- Cell F2  >> `=TEXT(E2;"dd/mm/yyyy")`
- Cell G2 >> `=TEXT(E2;"hh:mm")` or you can use `=TEXT(E2;"hh:mm AM/PM")`

---

**Obs1**.: My computer uses `dd/mm/yyyy` by default.

**Obs2**.: You can use the [`Cell Formatting`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8e10019e-d5d8-47a1-ba95-db95123d273e) to change the date and time masks.

Comment: Thanks dot.Py, thank you so much, it works.  How do or can I, reformat my Total Hours from (44.5), to your used time formatting (44:30:00)?

Comment: @Miaka3, by using "`Custom Formats`" at "`Cell Formatting GUI`". Take a look [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8e10019e-d5d8-47a1-ba95-db95123d273e).